# Problema com codificação Utf8 no Laravel

Tags: laravel, utf-8

Pessoal estou enfrentando um problema com a codificação UTF8, eu não sei o que acontece.
Quando imprimo o texto atráves do controller ele fica correto dessa forma http://prntscr.com/ofcemt.

Porém quando passo o texto para a view

```
return view('pagina_texto', compact('title','textoexemplo'));
```

O texto perde a codificação UFT8 e fica assim http://prntscr.com/ofce0t

Comment: Tenta imprimir assim: `{!! $textoexemplo !!}`

Comment: Muito obrigado amigo. Deus certinho era exatamente isso. Saberia me dizer a diferença entre {!! $textoexemplo !!} e a forma que estava usando {{ $textoexemplo }} ?

Comment: No `{!! !!}` Você salvar texto no banco banco com código html que ele entende, já no {{  }} traz exatemente o texto salvo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No Laravel você poder mostrar exatamente o conteúdo da sua string com `{{ }}`

Exemplo se você salvou assim:

```
| campo               |
| <h1>Bem vindo</h1>  |
```

Se usar assim:
{{ $campo }}

Ele vai mostrar exatamente assim:

```
 <h1>Bem vindo</h1>
```

Agora se usar assim:
{!! $campo !!}

Ele vai mostrar assim:

## Bem vindo

Faz a mesma função do [htmlentities](https://www.php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.htmlentities.php) do php

Espero ter ajudado

Comment: Valeu amigo, muito obrigado, ajudou muito sim. Entendi perfeitamente a explicação.